# Can one use a reversible hash algorithm as a compression function?

Tags: hash, sha-256, compression

As we know any input to SHA-256 will be returned as 64 hex length output. Is it possible to create a hash that can do the same thing as SHA-256 but can be reversed, so if we have the output of 64 length of hex number, we can reverse it and get started input like "i love programming"? This will be such a cool way to compress huge text. Is it possible?

Comment: You may be interested in "Compressive Sensing". In short it achieves a lossy compression with encryption.

Comment: Well strictly speaking, a hash function is always compressing, but I imagine you're talking about compressing data that can be losslessly decompressed.

Comment: This is information-theoretically impossible!

Comment: This would only work if the input has redundant information that is unnecessary for reconstructing it. That's true for all lossless compression algorithms. Also see [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)

Comment: If this were possible, someone would have already implemented it, because compressing a 10TB file **down to a few hundred bytes** would be God Damned Amazing and Incredibly Useful.

Comment: "This will be soo cool way to compress huge text" -- perpetual motion machines would also be soo cool.

Comment: 'Reversible hash' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: This would be the Lempel-Ziv "hashing" function, right?

Comment: @user207421 Not really, if you define "reversible" as "vulnerable to preimages". You can reverse some weak hashes or non-cryptographic hashes, but if the input space is large, you aren't able to tell _what_ input was the original input, just that _an_ input is equivalent (in the context of the hash function) to the original input. If the input is small enough then you can certainly reverse it. I'm sure you could find out what three byte ASCII English word was used to create a Fletcher64 hash...

Comment: If one of the answers helped, please mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 21):

Strictly speaking, all hash functions are compressing since the output can be smaller than the input, but I imagine you're asking about compressing data that can later be losslessly decompressed.

**This is impossible due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).** The fact that the fixed output space of a hash algorithm is [smaller than the input space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) means that there will always be multiple possible inputs for the same output. Even if you could find a preimage (i.e. "reverse" the hash), you would not know if it is the *original* preimage or just *a* preimage. If the input size was sufficiently small (smaller than the hash) then it may be possible since you can discard larger preimages and only keep the very finite number of small ones that make sense (e.g. only valid ASCII strings), but then it's not compression.

As an extreme example, imagine a "hash function" with a trivial preimage attack: a 1-bit CRC with the polynomial x + 1 (i.e. an even parity bit). If I give you the output of this function and the output is 1, you will have absolutely no idea what the input was. You can compute *an* input, but you can't find *the* input. For a 1-bit hash, half of all possible inputs in the input space map to that same output!

---

This impossibility is the basis of the [popular joke from Schneier Facts](https://www.schneierfacts.com/facts/164):

> For Bruce Schneier, SHA-1 is merely a compression algorithm.

Comment: The pigeon-hole principle also immediately proves that it's not possible to write a compression algorithm that can guarantee compression of every input by even **one bit**. There will always be some inputs that result in same-size-or-larger output.

Comment: There exist systems that use a perfect hash function. Perfect hash are hashing algorithms that are calculated based on fully known inputs (ie. all data that are not known beforehand are invalid to the system) thereby allowing you to calculate a hash function that never collides (there are even C libraries that can calculate this automatically for you). In a perfect hash the pigeonhole principle does not exist by definition. In such a system you should be able to reverse the hashing by generating all possible hashes and storing them in a table/database

Comment: @slebetman But then it's not compression anymore.

Comment: @slebetman In a finite domain of N known values, you can represent any of them by an integer between 1 and N. The process you described using a perfect hash is really just a very complicated way of representing the numbers from 1-N, in order to do that.

Answer (score 11):

- If the question was about ([current form](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/88377/3))

  **Reversible cryptographic hash functions**

  Then **No!**

  [**One-wayness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) property of the cryptographic secure hash functions will prevent that. Hash functions don't use keys. So if you can reverse, everybody will reverse and there will be no secure hash function at all.

  Besides, **mathematically impossible**, too; hash functions use arbitrary large inputs to digest a fixed size $\ell$

  $$H:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^\ell$$

  **Reversibility requires being 1-1 and onto**, you cannot reverse a function if it is not 1-1, and clearly, cryptographic hash functions are not 1-1 since the fixed output size.  1-1 is a bad property for cryptographic hash functions and what is described is a permutation.

  This can be seen clearly with [**Pigeonhole principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle); you have a small number of holes for arbitrarily numbered pigeons. Therefore at least one hole will contain more than one pigeon. When you try to map back, which pigeon will you choose? **fail!**

  Also, the Cryptographic Hash function needs to mangle the inputs to shrink the output and that causes to **loss of information** by the and operation ($\wedge$) that is not reversible.

  Therefore what you need is just the opposite of what we want from cryptographically secure hash functions. **The pre-image will fail!**
- If the question was about ([The first revision](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/3e714db1-ca38-4592-986d-564156e53d55/view-source))

  **compressible encryption;**

  Then **No!**

  Encryption schemes unlike hash functions are reversible operations. Therefore the output space must be at least the same as the input space.

  If you want to compress do it before encryption. Then you can decompress after decryption.

  $$c =E_k(compress(m)) \quad \text{ and } m =decompress(D_k(c))$$

  **However**, note that, the compression before encryption can be problematic as in the [CRIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME) (Compression Ratio Info-leak Made Easy);

  > CRIME (Compression Ratio Info-leak Made Easy) is a security exploit against secret web cookies over connections using the HTTPS and SPDY protocols that also use data compression. When used to recover the content of secret authentication cookies, it allows an attacker to perform session hijacking on an authenticated web session, allowing the launching of further attacks. CRIME was assigned [CVE-2012-4929](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-4929).

  The original paper - 2002 - John Kelsey - [Compression and Information Leakage of
  Plaintext](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2002/FSE/3091/3091.pdf)

  and the follow-up [BREACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BREACH)

  > BREACH (a backronym: Browser Reconnaissance and Exfiltration via Adaptive Compression of Hypertext) is a security exploit against HTTPS when using HTTP compression. BREACH is built based on the CRIME security exploit. BREACH was announced at the August 2013 Black Hat conference by security researchers Angelo Prado, Neal Harris and Yoel Gluck

  Another problem is achieving side-channel free compression as [noted by Hola](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88377/cryptography-for-compressing/88378?noredirect=1#comment194482_88378). If there is a side-channel attack possibility one might consider this, too.

  **Therefore, if you want to use compression before encryption execute a serious analysis of your decision.**

  Ironically, the modern encryption schemes do the reverse (increase the size - a little) due to security. Block/stream ciphers need IV/nonce to achieve Ind-CPA security. The modern mode of encryption methods like AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 produces an authentication tag that increases the output size, too.

Comment: It should be noted that compression before encryption can be problematic, since it generally breaks the security guarantee.

Comment: @Maeher yes, the CRIME attack. Are you also talking about the CPA game where the adversary sends two messages that have the same length, however, the challenger response includes the compression of the randomly selected message?

Comment: Well written. One associated problem is compression algorithms do not have side channel security.

Comment: @hola yes, that is another aspect to consider.

Answer (score -5):

**Yes**, it is possible provided you allow for hashes that are not necessarily a fixed length. This is essentially what content based addressing is. The content can be "any text, file, or byte" and it is addressed by a hash of it. For an example of this you can check out IPFS. You can share a short address of a file with someone else and they can decompress that hash back into the original piece of content. This works by maintaining a mapping between these addresses and the content.

While forest says that this is impossible due to the pigeonhole principle when using a fixed size hash output, IPFS gets around this by being able to support an arbitrary number of hash functions which can each have an arbitrary length. By varying the hash function or length you will always be able to find an address that is not currently used.

Comment: But that's not compression (think LZSS). That's just encoding.

Comment: What's the difference? Lossless compression can be defined as D(C(x)) = x where D is the decompression algorithm and C is the compression algorithm. For example C can be taking a SHA-256 hash of x and D can be looking up what's contained in a hash table at that hash. There is a trade off in using these kinds of tables in your compression / decompression algorithms since the table needs to be stored somewhere. An example of an algorithm using a table containing uncompressed content is Google's Brotli compression algorithm which uses a table of common words found in HTTP packets.

Comment: But that's not what OP is talking about. He's talking about hashing a large file into a small hash, then "reversing" the small hash back into the large file (of course not possible due to the pigeonhole principle).

Comment: And I am trying to point out that the limitation is not that important in the real world. Having 2^256 pigeon holes is plenty. I also described how IPFS gets around this problem if you needed more.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are claiming. The world will probably never need more than 2^252 distinct files, so we can compress any file that we need in the real world to just 256 bits? That is nonsensical, but it sort of seems like that is what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, you would be able to make an encoding scheme that encodes 2^252 (for example) distinct files. However, since you don't know the contents of the file in advance, you are effectively sending the entire file as an update to the compression algorithm every time you want to add a new file.

Comment: John, that is essentially what I am saying. The downside is that to achieve compression that big you essentially need to store a copy of the file somewhere else. Systems like bittorrent and IPFS distribute this giant dictionary over many machines. The goal of compression is to map "useful" strings of bits to short strings of bits and then short "unuseful" strings of bits would be mapped to longer ones. You ideally would want to have as high of density as possible from a short string of bits to a "useful" string of bits. The hard part is figuring out how to make such a mapping.

Comment: @Anonymous If you need to store a copy of the file somewhere else (or any information required for the reconstruction of the file), then it is not compression. Yes, DHT uses hashes. No, DHT is not a form of compression.

Comment: I am not sure why it is so hard to understand that this is compression. If I can send you a 64 byte long message and you are able to take that and reconstruct my original message of 1GiB, I would say that I was able to compress a 1 GiB message into 64 bytes. A DHT is not a form of compression, but rather a way to store a dictionary for going from hashes to data.

Comment: @Anonymous Unless that message contains _extreme_ redundancy, you won't be able to store 1 GiB in 64 bytes. And most _certainly_ not recover a 1 GiB preimage given a broken 512-bit (64 byte) hash.

Comment: Maybe another example not related to hashing can help explain how it is possible. Lets say I want to store 1TiB worth of images / videos, but only have 1MiB worth of space. I can upload those images / videos to the cloud and just save links to all of those images and videos. If I want to decompress a link I can just use wget. You might say this doesn't count as you have to add up the size of the file stored in the cloud and the size of the link, but that is not true. What you count is the data needed to retrieve the original file. A link is enough information to retrieve the original file.

Comment: @Anonymous I think you're misunderstanding what compression is. It doesn't matter _where_ the data is stored. The typical definition of compression in this context is use of a reversible algorithm which takes an input and produces an output. If the input is large and redundant, then the output is small and less redundant. It's as simple as that. If you store data in the cloud, that 1 TiB of data hasn't vanished just because you've moved it to another computer. It hasn't been compressed. It just moved.

Comment: The title "War and Peace" is not a compression of the novel "War and Peace" just because I can have a librarian retrieve the novel for me from the title.